# Font awesome some icon now showing up

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

im using font awesome 5.7.2 but for some reason not all icons are properly showing-up. At the below example only mail

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
```

is showing up. facebook etc only displayed as small squares.

this is how i add fontawesome to my site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome/5.7.2/all.css' %}">
```

Comment: you need `fab` for the facebook, twitter and google

Answer (score -1):

You are using fontawesome 4.7 version class. Try this for 5.7

```
<i class="far fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: `fa` is also valid : https://jsfiddle.net/dnqvfxz0/ (and he said that this one is working)

Comment: But what about facebook, twitter etc.?
Thanks so far

Comment: @Venom check the duplicate, you need `fab` for brand icons

Comment: Already got it ;) merci

Comment: @Venom may I simply ask why you accepted this answer? it doesn't solve the issue and by doing so you will make other people think it fixed your issue which is missleading [@shafikur nothing against you so please don't take this personnaly]

Comment: using fab instead of far works fine e.g.:
<i class="fab fa-google"></i>